# SVG is not rendering on other machines because of a font I used

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, fonts

Before I go any further I must say, I am fairly new to the world of SVGs.

I have a SVG with the following text drawn in it (with font `thesans_tt5_-webfont`).

> ABC.DEF

When I preview the SVG in any browser on my PC it works previews fine.

But on any other PC where the font is not installed, the text flows out of the SVG boundaries.
Upon editing in the Acrobat Illustrator it shows `X` (unknown symbol) on the `.`

Is there a way to make an svg which retains the font information in the file?
Or how can I make a SVG which will render properly independent of the fonts.